# Have a textbox expand horizontally and bleed into the column next to it in a rdlc?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have a sql server report, a rdlc, that generates a list of names with these columns:

```
Last   | First    | Middle
----------------------------
Last1    First1     Middle1
Last2    First2     Middle2
Last3    First3     Middle3
```

etc

Sometimes people like to put these really long company names in just the last name field. Is there a way I can have my rdlc expand the `Last` column to take over the other two columns?

```
Last   | First    | Middle
----------------------------
A Really Long Company Name
Last2    First2     Middle2
Last3    First3     Middle3
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add an extra row below the existing row (in the same Row Group if any).  In that row I would merge cells etc to get the required layout.  Then I would add opposing Visibility expressions (e.g. based on the length of a field) to both rows, to control which is shown for each row of data.

Comment: Oh that sounds like a good idea. I knew i could hide a specific field, like a textbox, based on a condition, but I didn't know I could hide a whhole row. Where do I set that?

Comment: Click the table, then right-click the row handle (just left of the first column), choose Row Visibility.